# Using FirePHP instead of var_dump

Tags: php, firefox-addon, var-dump, firephp

When I output a variable using `fb()` function it only output the variable value, is there any way so it show also variable type like what `var_dump` does? Nor show name of variable, it any one shows that world would be more beauty!

Comment: Maybe [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) helps? I don't know what you missing in `var_dump()`

Comment: @Bondye I missed the same thing that FirePHP developer missed `;)`

Comment: Never worked with FirePHP but doesn't just `FB::log(var_dump('Log message'));` works?

Comment: anyone reading this may also be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995307/sending-var-dump-to-firebug-console)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FB::log(gettype($var).":$var");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it easily enough.

```
function fb_dump() {
  ob_start();
  foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
    var_dump($arg);
  }
  $debug = ob_get_clean();
  fb($debug());
}

$foo = array(1, 5, 4);
$bar = "lorem ipsum";
fb_dump($foo, $bar);
```